# What packages would I use, (or are there examples) of typesetting system networks in LaTeX?

Tags: grammar

I'm looking to be able to typeset charts like the one below for a paper, and I'm wondering whether there are any examples of it anyone's come across; a quick search didn't turn anything usable up.

[System Networ Example http://www.linguistik-online.de/51_12/baumgarten_duboisPict/baumgarten_duboisPict3.jpg](http://www.linguistik-online.de/51_12/baumgarten_duboisPict/baumgarten_duboisPict3.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use PGF/TkiZ for this. Phylogenetic Trees look promising. Chapter 33 in the [manual](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).